# Annotations grouping using PSPDFKit

Tags: objective-c, pspdfkit

I started the work using PSPDFKit.  I'm trying to do something ... not sure if its doable or supported.  I'm trying to group a punch of annotations as one, like create a circle, square and a line, and group them together so I can move them together, copy/paste them as a unit. It's like creating a custom annotation that includes the 3 of them or any other annotations.

Thoughts?  I didn't try much here , don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of PSPDFKit. Please send your questions to peter@pspdfkit.com instead of StackOverflow. I'll be able to help you a lot faster if you use the intended way of support.

As for grouping, that's an interesting question - there's no code that would help you on that, you would need to study the source code quite a bit to add such a feature.